# Compiler says uuid.h not found but apt-get says it is

Tags: linux, makefile, posix

When compiling my C++ project that includes uuid.h I get the compile error:

> fatal error: uuid.h: No such file or directory

I'm not sure whats going wrong. It could be my compiler instructions are wrong or that I indeed dont have that file installed (but I don't think thats the problem).

> sudo apt-get install uuid-dev

The above command outputs: `uuid-dev is already the newest version`

My makefile is simply this:

```
all:
    g++ -o bin/myapplication src/main.cpp -std=c++11
```

**Edit:**
In .h file:

```
#include <uuid.h>
```

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: are you including it like `<uuid.h>` or `"uuid.h"`

Comment: @Deryck I am doing `#include <uuid.h>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bielive in newer version of the uuid the header is `<uuid/uuid.h>`

Answer (score 6):

The package's [file list](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/uuid-dev/filelist) shows that it contains `/usr/include/uuid/uuid.h`.  Since your default include path looks for files relative to `/usr/include`, you'd need to either write `<uuid/uuid.h>`, or add `-I/usr/include/uuid` to your compile options.

However, the package also provides a `.pc` file for use with [pkg-config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config), which is meant to abstract the details of which compiler options you need to build a program against a library.  If you run `pkg-config --cflags uuid` you get get the output `-I/usr/include/uuid`, and if you run `pkg-config --libs uuid`, you get the output `-luuid`.  These are meant to be incorporated into your program's build.

Since it looks like you're using Make, you should add these lines to your `Makefile`:

```
CFLAGS += `pkg-config --cflags uuid`
LDFLAGS += `pkg-config --libs uuid`
```

That'll incoroporate the necessary `-I` and `-l` options into your compile commands automatically — and it'll also work on other systems where the UUID library might be installed in a different location.